# How can I run the slideshow in a specified order?

Tags: software-recommendation, image-viewers, slideshow

I would like to view the images for example from the oldest until the newest. This is not possible with many viewers I tried (Mirage, Shotwell, Gnome Image Viewer).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[**gwenview**](http://gwenview.sourceforge.net/):

This is probably the best image viewer available at the moment. Built for KDE4, `Gwenview` comes with support for virtually all image formats out there, tools to do basic editing, tree-like file browser, support for tags, thumbnail previews, cropping, image rating system, slideshow, fullscreen mode, support for plugins and two view modes (Browse and View).

Let's install and use it:

```
sudo apt-get install gwenview
```

Now select your images and right-click on and choose **Open With ► Gwenview**

[image: file browser]

When the Gwenview GUI opens, select  **Sort By ► Date** under the **View** menu

[image: sort by dialog in GwenView]

Now your added images are sorted by date, just go to the **View** menu and select **Start Slideshow**

Don't forget: before **Start Slideshow** you should select all added images in the Gwenview window to select to show in **Slide show** mode. cool!

Also here are a lot of [Ubuntu Photo Slide Show applications](http://ubuntu.software.informer.com/download-ubuntu-photo-slide-show/).

Comment: Thank you! This is it. Too bad the settings do not permit to control the time interval between transitions.

Comment: Can you open several folders in it and maintain the order of images according to folder order?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I just wrote a plug-in that allows sorting by date. It works with the GNOME Image Viewer (EOG) and I tested on the latest Ubuntu 21.10 and it works great. You can download the plugin here: https://github.com/cybereality/eog-modified-date-plugin