# Multi photo slideshow software

Tags: software-recommendation, photo, slideshow

Hey everybody I'm looking for a program on Ubuntu that can make a slideshow of photo's in a directory and is able to show multiple photos at the same time filling up the screen.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the command-line tool `feh`:

```
sudo apt-get install feh
```

To view all pictures randomly in, for example the `~/Pictures` directory and all its subfolders, use the following command:

```
feh --recursive --randomize --auto-zoom --geometry 1600x1000 ~/Pictures
```

To view the pictures in their default geometry and in the order of the folder:

```
feh --recursive --auto-zoom ~/Pictures
```

You can find more information and keyboard shortcuts [here](http://xahlee.info/linux/linux_image_viewers.html).

Comment: cool! (+1)  `feh  -rZFD 4  . ` (= recursive + auto-zoom + fullscreen + delay=4s)

Answer (score 2):

Check Shotwell(comes Pre-Installed).

You can also try `F-spot Photo Manager`. [Click to install](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/f-spot)[image]

F-Spot is a full-featured personal photo management application for the GNOME desktop. It simplifies digital photography by providing intuitive tools to help you share, touch-up, find and organize your images. It allows for importing of your existing photo collections, tagging photos with identifiers, as well as doing simple edits of photos (e.g. rotating)

There is also [gwenview](http://gwenview.sourceforge.net/).

[image]

Install it by : `sudo apt-get install gwenview`

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43652/image-slideshow-application)

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/518819/how-can-i-run-the-slideshow-in-a-specified-order)